# NSFetchedResultsController wrong sort

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSManagedObject` subclass with `objectId: NSNumber` as an identifier. I have noticed, that `NSFetchedResultsController` with sort descriptor with key `objectId` sorts wrong. [Apple documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject) that we must not define properties with some reserved names (objectID, isInserted, isUpdated, isDeleted, etc). But `objectId` is not equal `objectID`. Does the sort goes wrong due to `objectId` property name? I have renamed this property to test my hypothesis, and it seems to be true. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not certain but I would not assume that the rule is case-sensitive, i.e. I wouldn't assume that `objectID` isn't the same as `objectId` and `OBJECTID`, etc...

Comment: Yes, the question is in case sensitivity. I can't find any confirmation.